# Import/Export of HP Fortify Audited Results

Tags: static-analysis, fortify

**Setup/Background:**

I work for a product that contains 500k+ LOC  predominantly (Java and Javascript). We have been running Fortify static analysis roughly for the past decade since Fortify 3.x/4.x. We use SSC to view and audit the analysis results. That way, the results are also made available to others in the team who may be interested in addition to the security leads.

Periodically, along with the code release, Fortify version is also upgraded and the metrics are migrated to a newer version. Fortify platform and upgrades are managed by a separate team. We just run the scan, upload the fpr. The results are automatically merged in SSC. Subsequently, we audit the newly found violations and re-mediate them appropriately. Usually for every release, there are hundreds of false-positives which are audited as *"Not an issue"*.

**Question:**

We are moving to a new platform - there would be a fresh installation of Fortify SSC managed by a different team altogether. If we perform an analysis and upload fpr to the new SSC instance, it may report one million+ violations. In reality, these violations have already been audited as *'Not an issue'* in our existing instance. We need a way to **"seed"** the newer instance with audited results from older instance.

**So, we would need some way to *export* the results from existing instance of Fortify SSC and *import* the same in the newer instance of Fortify SSC.**

From the existing instance, I know that I can **"Download Application File"** fpr from **'Application Artifacts'** that contains all the audited results. I would like to know if in the newer instance of SSC, by importing using **'Upload Artifact'**, will be audit data be seeded? So that, from the next scan, we can simply keep uploading the fpr files and the only the delta violations will be reported.

Existing Fortify SSC is on *version 17.20*. Newer platform Fortify instance would most likely be *version 18.10 or 17.20* but hopefully not below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

It works.

**Long Answer:**

1. I have *"Downloaded the Application File"* from an existing instance of Fortify SSC 17.20. This will typically be in the format - .fpr
2. I have installed another instance of Fortify SSC 17.20.
3. Later, I created a dummy Application and a Version for the project.
4. I have imported the earlier downloaded fpr from Step 1 using *"Upload Artifact"*. Now, the new instance of SSC took 3 days to completely import and provide audit/metrics etc
5. Ensure that the audit/metrics are same as the source SSC instance
6. Subsequently, performed a fresh scan and uploaded the new fpr.

Fortify SSC successfully merged and the artifacts. On subsequent uploads the existing audits are carried forward and no information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, give it a try. If this doesn't work, I think you can directly export the Database from the old instance, and import it to the new Database. If the two SSC versions are two far apart, the database schema may have changed a lot and the data transfer may be challenging. If you have issues, I would contact Fortify Support directly for help. They are usually responsive.

Comment: Yes, it works. I am not sure if DB export/import works the same way. SSC installation took some time but it was worth it!